# Refund on Cashiers Check?

Tags: united-states, cashier-check

If I get a cashiers check from my bank but decide not to use it, would my bank give me a refund for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, if you take an unused cashier's check that was drawn from your bank account back to the bank you got it from, they will cancel the cashier's check and issue a refund back to your account.

Answer (score 1):

<s>A cashiers check is [effectively cash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashier%27s_check), and can be cashed in as such at pretty much any financial institution you have an account with.</s> (This information is valid for [Certified Checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_check) only).

I've never had a situation where I cannot cancel a cashiers check from the institution that issued it if I'm the one who ordered it. YMMV, call the institution and ask if there is a procedure you need to follow, or if they will just cancel it for you (or if they won't).

You will not receive a refund for any processing fee by policy, but it never hurts to ask.

Comment: If it's already made out to someone do you think the bank would still allow me to cash it in instead of giving it to the person who it's made out to?

Comment: YMMV based on individual institutions, but I imagine if the person who ordered the check went in to cash it, there would not be much issue. You can call your bank to see if they have a specific policy they need you to follow as well.

Comment: Effectively cash to the person with their name in the 'To' line, not at all like cash for the one who had it issued.

Comment: @Hartco I was thinking of a different form of secured funding, you're absolutely correct. I've struck the original line and replaced it with something true.

Answer (score 1):

Real world data point:  I've done it.  There was a bit of a delay because I wanted it reissued for a slightly smaller amount and there wasn't enough money in the account to issue the new one without refunding the first one and I was not at the branch I had originally gotten it from.  Half an hour later I had my new check.